# Are there any tricks to getting auto-petters quickly after the Community Center was completed?

Tags: stardew-valley

I'm playing the 1.5 update of Stardew Valley, but I'm continuing an old save file where I already finished the Community Center bundles. So buying an auto-petter from Joja-Mart isn't an option anymore. I've seen I can get them as a reward from Skull Cavern treasure rooms though.

So far, I've been digging for about a year, with no success. If I have a very lucky day, I ignore harvesting and animal husbandry and use the warp totem to spend my whole day mining (while having eaten some spicy eel for extra luck and speed). On such days, I can get 0-5 treasure rooms (the 5 only happened once). If my days aren't extraordinarily lucky, I do my chores and basically spend the afternoon and evening mining, getting anywhere between 0-2 treasure rooms.

I've gotten a lot of stuff from the treasure rooms, but it seems to always be the same: dark cowboy hats, (mega) bombs, sprinklers, and cactus seeds. With very occasionally a seed maker or crystalarium.  Looking at [the wiki](https://stardewcommunitywiki.com/Skull_Cavern#Treasure_Rooms) the chance of getting an auto-petter should be about the same as getting all this other stuff, but even so I'm getting massive amounts of bombs and hats, and almost nothing of the other 1/25 chance stuff. This makes me think I'm doing things wrong.

Seeing as I need at least 2 auto-petters, and preferably would like 4 of them, are there any tricks I can use to acquire them faster? (I don't mind if that means 'cheating').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When on a console that allows it, save file editing as explained below is by far the fastest, as you can be done within a single in-game day. If you don't want to cheat like that, there are a few relatively fast 'legitimate' ways too:

- use Jade and Crystalariums (each will produce new jade every day and 16 hours in-game), then trade the Jade on Sundays with the desert trader for stairs. Use those stairs on the luckiest type of day with luck boosts from lucky rings and food/drinks.
- like [this comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/381497/are-there-any-tricks-to-getting-auto-petters-quickly-after-the-community-center#comment536224_381497) said, use money to buy stone, turn that stone into stairs as well. Use the same way as described in the previous point.
- do what SeanyBoi5 wrote in [their answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/382696/205399), and slay monsters in the 'dangerous' mines.

---

So, after trawling across the internet for a bit more, I came across [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBnq9Vd3MpU&t=593s) about 'luck level'. Increasing your luck level to an insane amount (like 1000) will make sure that floor 10 and every lower floor in the Skull Caverns is a Treasure Room. The youtube video lists a lot of other 'benefits' as well. Most importantly, Luck Level is something you can influence by doing save file editing, as the video doesn't disclose which mod allows the increase of luck level like it's shown there.

I ended up going with this, and found Auto-Petters on floors 40, 60, 66 and 131. I started immediately in the morning and was done at around 2PM (I did use a movement speed buff, spicy eel). If you want to, you can create extra inventory room by not bringing a pickaxe and only bring stairs to get down to floor 10, every treasure room will already have a stair. Do bring a weapon though as the treasure chambers still have enemies. Really, the weapon is the only thing you'll really need to bring.

I found a pretty good guide on generic save file editing [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/413150/discussions/0/405692758715239357/). The summary:  In your windows file explorer, go to `%appdata%`, your stardew valley save files will be in de Stardew Valley folder, under 'Saves'. Each farm you have will have it's own folder, named after your character + a number. **Copy the folder from the farm you'd like to edit to a save location as a backup first!** You never know what you might accidentally type/delete and need the backup. It's also good to have it to look up the original value of your luckLevel once you're done and want to set it back to normal.

For each save, you need to edit 2 files: SaveGameInfo and, in my case, Tink_241984836 (My character's name). Open them in Notepad, press ctrl + f, search for 'lucklevel', and change the value between the XML tags to 1000. (So you end up with `<luckLevel>1000</luckLevel>`). Save both files, and start the game. Happy treasure hunting!

And **once you're done and want to mine the Skull Cavern as usual again, you need to change your save file once again**, and set the luckLevel back to it's original number (in my case, 0). The setting persists, so if you don't, you'll have this extreme amount of 'luck' every day and will never be able to mine the Skull Cavern normally again.

Answer (score 1):

If the normal mines is in its “dangerous” state (increased difficulty) 0.2% of monsters or slimes with a gold star (1.2% chance of a slime having a gold star) have a 2% chance to drop one. You can activate “Dangerous” using the shrine of challenge at the bottom after completing the Qi Quest “Danger in the deep” or just get an auto-petter during the “Danger in the deep” quest. I recommend using the burglar ring for a higher chance at getting an auto-petter, and luck ring to increase chance of gold star slimes/“special” monsters which drop the auto-petter.

Edit: Those “Special Monsters” have a 14% chance to drop any item that can be found in a treasure room, which can include an auto-petter (1/25)